# Show setup Google Pay dialog

Tags: android, google-pay

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it some api to check did user enter all information to the Google Pay?

[isReadyToPay](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) Works like can use this api or not.

> User either has or can add a card

2. Is it possible to show Setup Google Pay dialog not by press Google Pay button.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you add the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/object#IsReadyToPayRequest) body, the response will include additional information about the user's readiness to pay with at least one the allowed payment methods specified in the request (through `allowedPaymentMethods`).
2. If you are referring to the label in the button "Buy with Google Pay", this can't be changed at the moment.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is there anyway to redirect user to Google Pay app and setup card, then redirect back to original app automatically when done ?

Comment: btw, I checked on Google API developer document and it seem `IsReadyToPayResponse` with `paymentMethodPresent` property is only available for web